# How to specify match firsting closing bracket, it is always matching the last

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string like this -

```
"UberMedia/".base64_decode("RWNobw==")."fon/Tablet/App/iOS/".base64_decode("EWNobw==")."fon/".base64_decode("TWNobw==")."fon"
```

I would like to collect all the strings inside the base64_decode()'s i.e. the following three strings in this case-

```
1. "RWNobw=="
2. "EWNobw=="
3. "TWNobw=="
```

**I tried**

With the following regular expression -

```
preg_match_all("/base64_decode\(\"(.*)\"\)/",$string,$matches);
```

I am getting this output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => base64_decode("RWNobw==")."fon/Tablet/App/iOS/".base64_decode("EWNobw==")."fon/".base64_decode("TWNobw==")
    [1] => RWNobw==")."fon/Tablet/App/iOS/".base64_decode("EWNobw==")."fon/".base64_decode("TWNobw==
)
```

You can see that it is matching the last occurance of `")` in the string (spanning across the first and the third base64_decode() functions).

How do I change it such that all the three occurrences of base64_decode()'s are considered individually and I can get the three strings as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

By default the quantifiers (`*` in this case) will match as much as possible. You could use a lazy quantifier instead by adding a `?` after it, like:

```
base64_decode\("(.*?)"\)
```

Or even better restrict what the content of the group can match, for example:

```
base64_decode\("([^"\s]*)"\)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
/(?<=base64_decode\()[^)]+(?=\))/
```

These are non-capturing groups (before and after the `[^)]`and will return exactly what you need:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "RWNobw=="
        [1] => "EWNobw=="
        [2] => "TWNobw=="
    )

)
```

Specifically:

- `(?<=base64_decode\()` Matches a group before your main expression without including it in the result.
- `(?=\))` Matches a group after your main expression without including it in the result.
- `[^)]+` is the main expression, which matches any character which is not a closed bracket

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem, i am pasting the code i did the test with.

```
$string = '"UberMedia/".base64_decode("RWNobw==")."fon/Tablet/App/iOS/".base64_decode("EWNobw==")."fon/".base64_decode("TWNobw==")."fon"';

preg_match_all("/(base64_decode\(\"[A-Za-z0-9=]+\"\))/",$string,$matches);


print_r($matches);
```

Will produce

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => base64_decode("RWNobw==")
            [1] => base64_decode("EWNobw==")
            [2] => base64_decode("TWNobw==")
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => base64_decode("RWNobw==")
        [1] => base64_decode("EWNobw==")
        [2] => base64_decode("TWNobw==")
    )
```

)